# JavaFX, Casting ArrayList to ObservableList

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, ormlite, observablelist

Is there a way to cast `ArrayList` to `ObservableList`? I would like to do it without iterating through `ArrayList`.

To be more specific, I am using ORMLite to get data from database, and I need `ObservableList` as an output of the method fetching data from DB.

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
ArrayList<Stavka> listStavaka = new ArrayList<>(); 
Dao<Stavka, Integer> stavkaDao = DaoManager.createDao(connection, Stavka.class);
listStavaka = (ArrayList<Stavka>) stavkaDao.queryForAll();
ObservableList<Stavka> oListStavaka = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
for (Stavka stavka : listStavaka) {
    oListStavaka.add(stavka);
}
```

And I would like to do something like this:

```
ObservableList<Stavka> listStavaka = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
Dao<Stavka, Integer> stavkaDao = DaoManager.createDao(connection, Stavka.class);
listStavaka = (ObservableList<Stavka>) stavkaDao.queryForAll();
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can do

```
ObservableList<Stavka> oListStavaka = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listStavaka);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

As in Uluk Biy's answer, but if you don't want to mix it with new list by FXCollections,
just use this...

```
oListStavaka.addAll(stavkaDao.queryForAll());
```