# Casting ArrayList<> to ObservableList<> for TableView

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

all!

While I designed my project on Java I encountered the following principal problem:

The program I need to write is interface that allows user to input some data and then save it in specific format. Within the project I store data in `ArrayList<>`.

```
public class CQuestionnaire
{

    // fields
    private final List<CQuestStage> m_lstStages;
    …
}
```

User interface is based on TableView. So I need `ObservableList<>` to connect data and `TableView`. As I think it will be good decision to link `TableView` with the list from `CQuestionnaire` directly. So I implemented `getObservableList()` for this purpose:

```
public class CQuestionnaire
{
    // fields
    private final List<CQuestStage> m_lstStages;

    public ObservableList<CQuestStage> getObservableList()
    {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(m_lstStages);
    }
    …
}
```

This doesn’t work because `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` returns copy of the list and all user’s actions don’t change on `CQuestionnaire` member.

The question is the following: is there any approach how to link `TableView` with the `ArrayList<>` without changing its type to `ObservableList<>` (to leave data and its view separately) and without creating distinct list that is necessary for `TableView` only?

Of course I’ve read this topic ([JavaFX, Casting ArrayList to ObservableList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191954/javafx-casting-arraylist-to-observablelist)). But the problem is that `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` copies list there is no link between source list in `CQuestionnaire` and `TableView`.

Comment: Just so you know, per the Javadocs, `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` does not actually return a copy of the list. The docs specifically say that the new list is backed by the provided one, however it also specifically mentions that only mutations on the new observable list will be reported to observers.

Comment: What do you need? Do you just need the current state of the ArrayList? Or do you need to get informed whenever the ArrayList changes?

Comment: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-java.util.Collection-] says that it "Creates a new observable array list and adds a content of collection col to it."

Comment: The simplest thing is to use `ObservableList` in your `CQuestionnaire` class. Is there a reason you don't do this?

Comment: @Florian Schaetz, I need to change my ArrayList (add, edit and remove items) avoiding change of its type. A kind of casting ArrayList to Observable list to allow user to change it via TableView

Comment: @sillyfly: The reasons to avoid changing type to ObservableList are: (1)CQuestionnaire is data storing object. This is not too good to implement interface features within it. (2) is serializaiton - if I change its type I need to leave it observable in all projects where I want to load data of this type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`FXCollections.observableList(m_lstStages)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-), which returns an observable list backed by the specified list, instead of `FXCollections.observableArrayList(m_lstStages)`, which creates a new observable array list and adds the content of the collection to it.

That way, changes made to the content of the table view will automatically propagate back to the original list. (Note though, that while changes to the underlying list will change the observable list, since the underlying list is not observable there is no way for the table to be informed of such changes, so it can't automatically update.)

Note there is no real need to add this functionality to your model class; you can just wrap the list with `FXCollections.observableList(...)` at the point you need it. This prevents your model having a dependency on the JavaFX API, which I assume is part of the aim here.

Here's a simple SSCCE.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValueBase;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithModelWithPlainList extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Model model = new Model();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 20 ; i++) {
            model.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, i*i));
        }

        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();

        // use observable list wrapping model data for table items:
        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(model.getItems()));

        // normal table setup:

        table.getColumns().add(column("Item", Item::getName));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Value", Item::getValue));

        // controls to modify table data:

        TextField itemNameField = new TextField();
        Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(1, 1000, 200);
        Button add = new Button("Add");

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> addHandler = e -> {
            table.getItems().add(new Item(itemNameField.getText(), spinner.getValue()));
            itemNameField.clear();
        };
        add.setOnAction(addHandler);
        itemNameField.setOnAction(addHandler);

        Button remove = new Button("Remove");
        remove.disableProperty().bind(table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
        remove.setOnAction(e -> table.getItems().remove(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()));

        // checks that model and table are in sync:

        Button debug = new Button("Debug");
        debug.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println("Model has "+model.getItems().size()+" items; table has "+table.getItems().size()+" items");
            for (int i = 0 ; i < model.getItems().size() && i < table.getItems().size(); i++) {
                Item modelItem = model.getItems().get(i);
                Item tableItem = table.getItems().get(i);
                System.out.printf("Index %d: model %s (%d); table %s (%d); equal: %s%n",
                        i, modelItem.getName(), modelItem.getValue(),
                        tableItem.getName(), tableItem.getValue(),
                        tableItem.getValue()==modelItem.getValue() && tableItem.getName().equals(modelItem.getName()));
            }
            System.out.println();
        });

        // layout stuff:

        HBox controls = new HBox(2, itemNameField, spinner, add, remove, debug);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        root.setBottom(controls);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S,T> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ObservableValueBase<T>() {
            @Override
            public T getValue() {
                return property.apply(cellData.getValue());
            };
        });
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Model {
        private List<Item> items ;

        public Model() {
            this.items = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public List<Item> getItems() {
            return items ;
        }
    }

    public static class Item {
        private String name ;
        private int value ;

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            this.name = name ;
            this.value = value ;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried several experiments and it become more clear but you example makes the topic clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a listener which you can use to update the ArrayList.
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#addListener(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener)

Comment: Thank you. It looks like a good plan for correct Data-View model implementation

Comment: There is no need to do that, you can just get an observable list backed by the original.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like there’s need to add listener. After I used FXCollections.observableList() instead of FXCollections.observableArrayList() things went better – I see that data is changing – I call TableView.getItems() and data is correct there. But changes of list don’t invoke table redraw. So it’s necessary to invoke it manually. 
Now I work over it because I’m very new in Java :)

Comment: Hmm: if you change the data via the observable list, then the table will change (if it doesn't, you are doing something else wrong). But if you change the data in the plain `ArrayList` (which is not observable and doesn't support any listeners of any kind), then of course the table cannot possibly know about it. If you want changes directly made to `m_lstStages` to update the view, the *only* option you have is to make `m_lstStages` itself an `ObservableList`.