# Convert Collection(java.util.Collection) to Observable(io.reactivex.Observable) in java 8

Tags: java-8, rx-java

Is there any API method to convert Collection (java.util.Collection) to Observable (io.reactivex.Observable) ?

Let's say I have one collection, I want to convert the same to Observable. How can I do the same?

```
Collection<SchoolList> s = new ArrayList<>();
 s.addAll(sl);
```

Comment: are you looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191954/javafx-casting-arraylist-to-observablelist?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables

Answer (score 0):

The observable factory method `Observable.fromIterable(collection)` is likely what your looking to use. See also the [docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables#fromiterable)